# Django - edit an object that already exist?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm having a problem when I want to edit my record.

it does edit everything ok, but tried to add `get_or_create` so if exists don't create, but it's not working as expected.

Can someone help me?

```
def edit(request, id):
    models = [hotel, person]
    for model in models:
        try:
            instance = model.objects.get(id=id)
            if instance == hotel.objects.get(id=id):
                form = hotelForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
                if form.is_valid():
                    obj, created = hotel.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
                    if not created:
                        messages.error(request, 'error. Already exists')
                    else:
                        form.save()
                        messages.success(request, 'Success!')
                        return redirect('/')
        except:
            try:
                if instance == person.objects.get(id=id):
                    form = personForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        messages.success(request, 'Sucess!')
                        return redirect('/')
            except:
                pass

    return render(request , "edit.html", {'form': form})
```

note:
My model `person` works ok without the `get_or_create` but if I want to add it as in the first model `hotel` it won't work.

How can I make it work as expected?

Comment: Your code is very unclear. I suggest that you specify which error types you are catching in your `except` calls, so that we can understand the flow a bit easier. It may also be worth while for you to go back to some basic Django tutorials on writing edit views.

Comment: First things first, for whatever reason you are trying to do this it seems like a poor programming practice. Have two different actions for editing each model that will make it simpler to understand. You are losing separation of concerns principle.

Comment: Define "not working", what *does* happen?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't make sense on several fronts. I will start with the most dangerous

```
       try:

       except:
            pass
```

Never ever do this. You must always catch specific exceptions and handle each one individually. On the rare occaision when you have no choice but to catch all exceptions with one statements you **absolutely must** log it so that you know what's happening inside your code.

The second major issue is this:

```
models = [hotel, person]
    for model in models:
        ...
    if instance == hotel.objects.get(id=id):
        ...
    if instance == person.objects.get(id=id):
```

You are assuming that hotels and objects have the same id. Once in a blue moon you might get such a pair purely as a coincidence. the primary keys for hotels and for persons have absolutely no relation to each other.